# I need some guidance with a RegEx pattern

Tags: regex

I need to test some strings to see if they match an expression but I am not at all familiar with RegEx. Looking for some help in what the patterns should be.
The following are some of the string and how I hope they will test:

```
TEIJB502 -OK
TT3010 -OK
TT3110 -OK
TT692A -FAIL
ZT60101 -OK
AT1 -OK
AT101A -FAIL
AT101B -FAIL
AT1786A -FAIL
AT1786B -FAIL
```

In other words, pass/fail based on the presence of the suffix at the end.

I then need to run a RegEx and Pass the ones above that failed, and Fail the ones that passed.

I know it sounds counter-productive but I need a way to determine how I will parse out each string into separate columns of a table.  IE:

```
Type    Number    Suffix
TEIJB    502
TT       3010
TT       692       A
```

Comment: It could be of use for us to know what kind of pattern do you want to reproduce. RegEx are useful when you want to identify and isolate a given pattern out of your data. If you have this information, please edit your question. If this sounds confusing, an example would be "A RegEx that matches 8-characters long strings with only numbers in it".

Comment: I could be any number of characters long.  It will alway start with Alpha characters then numeric.  It may or may not end with an alpha character.  I guess what i was thinking is that I would have some type of if statement that said if the string matches any number of Alpha and any number if digits then i will parse out one way, otherwise it will have any number of Alpha, any number of digits, and any number of Alpha again and i will parse it a different way.  If RegEx is not the best way to do this then I sorry for any confusion.  I’ll gladly try and research a different method

Comment: So, what language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A frequent fallacy with regular expressions is thinking one needs to use a single regex when multiple would be clearer and more concise. In this case, it's just the opposite: one fairly simple regex can separate the columns extremely efficiently.

How to read capture groups depends on the language you're in, but capture groups are usable in all languages that support regex. Use:

```
^([A-Z]+)(\d+)([A-Z])?$
```

Answer (score 0):

By only looking at your above example:

```
TEIJB502 -OK
TT3010 -OK
TT3110 -OK
TT692A -FAIL
ZT60101 -OK
AT1 -OK
AT101A -FAIL
AT101B -FAIL
AT1786A -FAIL
AT1786B -FAIL
```

I did the following in Notepad++ on a Windows 10 PC:

Run Notepad++;

press ctrl+h; and

make sure to be in Regular expression mode

```
Find what: (^\D+)(\d{1,5})(\D)
```

and then

```
Replace with: \1\t\2\t\3\t
```

I'm sure you'll fine tune it on your own. This is how I would start experimenting with your given example on my own.

My approach is that I would capture groups, keep them and insert a tab inbetween all of them.

I'm looking for non-digit chars in the beginning with `(^\D+)` . This is my first capture group.

I'm looking for digits in the second capture group with `(\d{1,5}`. This is to tell Notepad++ that I'm looking for digits that are 1 to 5 digit long.

I'm looking for non-digit chars again in the last capture group with `(\D)`. This is to find your suffix at the end.

The Replace with pattern only tells to keep the capture groups `\1` `\2` `\3` but I insert a tab `\t` between them. Thus `\1\t\2\t\3\t`.

Your 'Find what' pattern can and should be more generic than mine. Hope I could be of some help to you anyway.

Regards,
M.